# How to integrate subquery with other table and grab name column?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, group-by, distinct

I had searching application, finding personal information which had been filtered by some criteria (category, years of experience etc) from itemregistrationpangkat table:

```
 itemregistrationpangkatID|itemregistrationID|NegeriID|yeartamatkhidmat|yearmulakhidmat
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
                1         |        2         |  Kedah  |      2001    |   2002
                2         |        2         |  Kedah  |      2003    |   2007
                3         |        3         | Melaka  |     2008     |   2012
                4         |        3         | Melaka  |     2013     |   2018
                5         |        4         |    KL   |     2000     |   2001


 itemregistrationID   |  name | SectionID     | CategoryID  
  -----------------------------------------------------------
           1          |  Eric |     1         |     2     
           2          |  Tom  |     2         |     4      
           3          | Anne  |     2         |     4     
           4          | Marie |     3         |     2      
           5          | Bill  |     1         |     3
```

I had problem with the last filter, 'tempoh perkhidmatan by negeri'. I need to calculate the number of working experience by state(negeri). For example, when searching for people of 5 years in the state(negeri) 'x', the sql will sum years of experience of each person in the state selected.

This is the full code of SQL searching by criteria:

```
   $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->join('sections', 'itemregistrations.SectionID', '=', 'sections.SectionID')
                ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.CategoryID', '=', 'categories.CategoryID')
                ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.OperasiID', '=', 'operasi.OperasiID')
                ->join('negeri', 'itemregistrations.NegeriID', '=', 'negeri.NegeriID')
                ->join('gred', 'itemregistrations.GredID', '=', 'gred.GredID')
                ->where('itemregistrations.statusProID', '=', 1)
                ->select('itemregistrations.name','sections.sectionname', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'itemregistrations.lahir_yy', 'itemregistrations.pdrm_yy', 'gred.namagred', 'itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID', '');

        if($request->input('negeri_lahir') != ''){
            $query->where('itemregistrations.NegeriID', $request->input('negeri_lahir'));
        }

        if($request->input('kategori') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.CategoryID', $request->input('kategori'));
        }

        if($request->input('pangkat') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.OperasiID', $request->input('pangkat'));
        }

        if(request('umur')) {
            $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);  
        }

        if($request->input('gred') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.GredID', $request->input('gred'));
        }

        if(request('tempoh')) {
            $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - pdrm_yy >= ?', [request('tempoh')]);  
        }

        if($request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan') != '') {
            $query->join('itemregistrationpangkat', 'itemregistrationpangkat.itemRegistrationID', '=', 'itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID')
                ->where('itemregistrationpangkat.NegeriID', $request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan'));           
        }

      if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('m.itemRegistrationID, sum(m.duration)'))
                  ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
                        RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID'))
                  ->distinct()
                  ->groupBy('m.itemRegistrationID');
      }

   $newitem = $query->get();

   return response::json($newitem);
```

The code involve to be solve is this(the last filter):

```
    if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('m.itemRegistrationID, sum(m.duration)'))
                  ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
                        RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID'))
                  ->distinct()
                  ->groupBy('m.itemRegistrationID');
      }
```

The problem is duplicate rows.
The above console log shows:

```
 0:
 itemRegistrationID: 791
 sum(m.duration): 6
```

supposely:

```
 0:
 itemRegistrationID: 791
 sum(m.duration): 3
```

The distinct() is not working with groupby, if I remove groupby it can remove the duplicate rows.

Comment: So, did you solve it?

Comment: No, the duplication still exist. I need groupby. I cannot use distinct() alone

Comment: If I see you last query, you are doing a `RIGHT JOIN`. Is there a particular reason why it need to be a `RIGHT JOIN`? Because you know that it will return all value from the right side of the join, right?

Comment: I do right join because I tried to get the itemregistration columns as it returns error if I select using previous $query sql statement but still fail to do so. It returns another error, ambigous error for itemregistrationID as it exist in both itemregistration table and itemregistrationpangkat table

Comment: I select from subquery selection caused 2 times duplication of the same row when I console log the query.

Comment: Ok, now back to your main concern is why there are duplicated value during the last query. Can I have a sample of data from `itemregistrationpangkat` and `itemregistration` table?

Comment: What if `distinct()` removed? Will it give a correct value? And can you try with `SUM(DISTINCT m.duration)` in your `SELECT`?

Comment: I update the question with table and I had removed distinct(). I tried your suggestion, to use distinct in sum and it works!! Brilliant idea! I don't know that distinct can be used in sum().

Comment: Can you post it as answer and some explaination why sum add the duration of duplication?

Comment: you post the answer I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why it shows duplication is because of the `RIGHT JOIN`. I have tested the same condition myself and below is my testing example:

```
--Lets say my itemregistrations table look like this:
+----------------------+-------------+------------+
|  itemRegistrationID  |  firstname  |  lastname  |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+
|                   1  |  A          |  B         |
|                   2  |  C          |  D         |
|                   3  |  E          |  F         |
|                   1  |  A          |  A         |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+
-- notice that there are repeated value of = 1 in itemregistrationID

-- And my itemregistrationpangkat table look like this:
+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|  itemRegistrationID  |  NegeriID  |  yeartamatkhidmat  |  yearmulakhidmat  |
+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|                   1  |  J         |  2019-04-26        |  2009-12-01       |
|                   2  |  S         |  2018-12-31        |  1999-08-19       |
|                   3  |  P         |  2017-12-31        |  2001-03-02       |
+----------------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I extracted your MySQL query above to become this:

```
SELECT m.itemRegistrationID, SUM(m.duration)
FROM 
    (SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, 
    YEAR(yeartamatkhidmat) - YEAR(yearmulakhidmat) AS duration 
    FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations 
ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID  
GROUP BY m.itemRegistrationID;

-- with the query above, my results are as following:
+----------------------+-------------------+
|  itemRegistrationID  |  sum(m.duration)  |
+----------------------+-------------------+
|                   1  |               20  |
|                   2  |               19  |
|                   3  |               16  |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

In order to see what causes id=1 to have duplicated value, I do a query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, 
    YEAR(yeartamatkhidmat) - YEAR(yearmulakhidmat) AS duration 
    FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations ON 
itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID;

-- and it shows the following result:
+----------------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+
|  itemRegistrationID  |  NegeriID  |  duration  |  itemRegistrationID  |  firstname  |  lastname  |
+----------------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+
|                   1  |  J         |        10  |                   1  |  A          |  B         |
|                   1  |  J         |        10  |                   1  |  A          |  A         |
|                   2  |  S         |        19  |                   2  |  C          |  D         |
|                   3  |  P         |        16  |                   3  |  E          |  F         |
+----------------------+------------+------------+----------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Of course by adding `SUM(DISTINCT m.duration)` in your `SELECT` it will remove any `m.duration` duplicates. This is where I'm concern about. I don't think `m.duration` should be the factor of deciding duplicates because you have `itemregistrationID` and `NegeriID` so the combination of that should be something unique (or at least some combination from other fields than those two that will be unique). My further testing shows that if `itemregistrationpangkat` table have two `itemRegistrationID` with different `NegeriID` etc.,  `SUM(DISTINCT m.duration)` won't work. Let me try something and update my answer if I found a better way.

**UPDATE:**
I have created a fiddle here: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpSLKVd9LfGP1RHZ5HAsws/0)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and explanation. your explanation is very good and understandable. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: If you can have a look on related question with the above it would be great. thanks.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860103/how-to-get-other-column-value-in-different-table-into-the-query

Comment: You're welcome @joun .. but as I explain in the last paragraph, I think there are still some work to do in order for you to get the most accurate result. Please test all the possible condition and update me if there's something wrong with the query or hopefully this can help you find your way of getting the correct result.

Comment: okay, thank you for the reminder. I will test them with more data to check whether the query is accurate or not.