# How to get other column value in different table into the query?

Tags: sql, laravel-5, subquery

I had searching application, finding personal information which had been filtered by some criteria (category, years of experience etc)

I had problem with the last filter, 'tempoh perkhidmatan by negeri'. I need to calculate the number of working experience by state(negeri). For example, when searching for people of 5 years in the state(negeri) 'x', the sql will sum years of experience of each person in the state selected.

This is the full code of SQL searching by criteria:

```
   $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->join('sections', 'itemregistrations.SectionID', '=', 'sections.SectionID')
                ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.CategoryID', '=', 'categories.CategoryID')
                ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.OperasiID', '=', 'operasi.OperasiID')
                ->join('negeri', 'itemregistrations.NegeriID', '=', 'negeri.NegeriID')
                ->join('gred', 'itemregistrations.GredID', '=', 'gred.GredID')
                ->where('itemregistrations.statusProID', '=', 1)
                ->select('itemregistrations.name','sections.sectionname', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan', 'itemregistrations.lahir_yy', 'itemregistrations.pdrm_yy', 'gred.namagred', 'itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID', '');

        if($request->input('negeri_lahir') != ''){
            $query->where('itemregistrations.NegeriID', $request->input('negeri_lahir'));
        }

        if($request->input('kategori') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.CategoryID', $request->input('kategori'));
        }

        if($request->input('pangkat') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.OperasiID', $request->input('pangkat'));
        }

        if(request('umur')) {
            $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);  
        }

        if($request->input('gred') != '') {
            $query->where('itemregistrations.GredID', $request->input('gred'));
        }

        if(request('tempoh')) {
            $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - pdrm_yy >= ?', [request('tempoh')]);  
        }

        if($request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan') != '') {
            $query->join('itemregistrationpangkat', 'itemregistrationpangkat.itemRegistrationID', '=', 'itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID')
                ->where('itemregistrationpangkat.NegeriID', $request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan'));           
        }

      if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('m.itemRegistrationID, sum(m.duration)'))
                  ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
                        RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID'))
                  ->distinct()
                  ->groupBy('m.itemRegistrationID');
      }

   $newitem = $query->get();

   return response::json($newitem);
```

The code involve to be solve is this(the last filter):

```
    if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('m.itemRegistrationID, m.NegeriID, sum(distinct m.duration)'))
                  ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT itemRegistrationID, NegeriID, yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m 
                  RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID=m.itemRegistrationID'))
                  ->groupBy('m.itemRegistrationID', 'm.NegeriID'); 
      }
```

The problem is I need to get name column, sectionID column, CategoryID, OperasiID, NegeriID, GredID, from itemregistrations table from the $query statement. How to combine the last query filter in 'tempoh_negeri' with the previous one?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know about Laravel in particular, so I had much trouble trying to understand how your query was built, but this syntax seems to enable people to write a request by adding chunks, but not necessarily in the right order. So here's what I believe your query is supposed to do, for SQL speakers:

```
SELECT itemregistrations .name,
       sections          .sectionname,
       categories        .categoryname,
       operasi           .operasiname,
       itemregistrations .Nobadan,
       itemregistrations .lahir_yy,
       itemregistrations .pdrm_yy,
       gred              .namagred,
       itemregistrations .itemRegistrationID
-- if($tempoh_negeri)           (request)
      ,m                 .itemRegistrationID,
       sum(m.duration)

  FROM itemregistrations
-- if($tempoh_negeri)           (request)
     ,(SELECT DISTINCT itemRegistrationID,
                       NegeriID,
                       yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat as duration

         FROM itemregistrationpangkat) AS m

   RIGHT JOIN itemregistrations
           ON itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID = m.itemRegistrationID


  JOIN sections
    ON itemregistrations.SectionID = sections.SectionID

  JOIN categories
    ON itemregistrations.CategoryID = categories.CategoryID

  JOIN operasi
    ON itemregistrations.OperasiID  = operasi.OperasiID

  JOIN negeri
    ON itemregistrations.NegeriID   = negeri.NegeriID

  JOIN gred
    ON itemregistrations.GredID     = gred.GredID

-- if($negeri_perkhidmatan)
  JOIN itemregistrationpangkat
    ON itemregistrationpangkat.itemRegistrationID = itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID


 WHERE itemregistrations.statusProID = 1

-- if($negeri_lahir) (WHERE)
   AND itemregistrations.NegeriID           = $negeri_lahir

-- if($kategori)     (WHERE)
   AND  itemregistrations.CategoryID        = $kategori

-- if($pangkat)      (WHERE)
   AND itemregistrations.OperasiID          = $pangkat

-- if(umur)          (WHERERAW) (request)
   AND YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy          >= umur

-- if($gred)         (WHERE)
   AND itemregistrations.GredID             = $gred

-- if($tempoh)       (WHERERAW) (request)
   AND YEAR(CURDATE()) - pdrm_yy           >= tempoh

-- if($negeri_perkhidmatan)
   AND itemregistrationpangkat.NegeriID     = $negeri_perkhidmatan

-- if($tempoh_negeri)           (request)
GROUP BY m.itemRegistrationID
```

If it's so, you cannot do what you want following that way (including main columns into the subquery) because your subquery will be evaluated BEFORE the main one is.

Instead, you need to write a proper filter at main query level, that is : among the others "JOIN…ON" clauses already in place. Which would give:

```
LEFT JOIN itemregistrationpangkat
       ON itemregistrationpangkat.itemRegistrationID = itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID
```

… then specify the substraction directly in your `sum()` function

```
          sum(yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidma)
```

As regards Lavarel, this probably would give something like:

```
 if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
    $query->leftjoin('itemregistrationpangkat','itemRegistrationID','=','itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID');
    $query->select(DB:raw('sum(yeartamatkhidmat - yearmulakhidmat'));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your idea had same logic with my solution (just got) by joining itemregistrationpagkat first then get the sum query after that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Even though it was rather late, please consider validate the answer if you believe it can fit people's need.

Also, you added a bounty to this request, which is now lost just because of a few hours overdue. Not a big deal, of course, but that's just too bad… :-)